# Can I make a command to shutdown a discord bot that only trusted members can use? [PYTHON/DISCORD.PY]

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py, logout

We have tried so many solutions but nothing works.
This is what we have so far (with personal details removed for safety reasons).

```
@bot.command(aliases=['disconnect', 'close', 'stopbot'])
async def logout(ctx):
    if ctx.guild.id is not serverIdHere:
        return
    else:
        role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Trusted Developer")
        if role in ctx.author.roles:
            await ctx.send(f"Ok")
            await bot.logout()
        else:
            return
```

Any help would be super appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want users with a specific role

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_role('id_here or name')
async def logout(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Shutting down')
    await bot.logout()
```

if you want so only the owners can user it

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def logout(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Shutting down')
    await bot.logout()
```

if you want specific users id's, there are three options

1.

```py
def is_valid_user(ctx):
    return ctx.author.id in my_list_of_ids

@bot.command()
@commands.check(is_valid_user)
async def logout(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Shutting down')
    await bot.logout()
```

2. 

```py
def can_use_this_command():
    async def predicate(ctx):
        return ctx.author.id in my_list_of_ids
    return commands.check(predicate)

@bot.command()
@can_use_this_command()
async def logout(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Shutting down')
    await bot.logout()
```

3. 

```py
@bot.command()
async def logout(ctx):
    if ctx.author.id not in my_list_if_ids:
        return

    await ctx.send('Shutting down')
    await bot.logout()
```

Reference:

- [has_role](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=has_role#discord.ext.commands.has_role)
- [is_owner](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=is_owner#discord.ext.commands.is_owner)
- [checks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#checks)

Comment: That solution worked marvelously! Thank you so much.